# css for media print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so I have this code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>...</div>
    <table id="printthis">
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            ...
            ...
        </tr>
    </table>
    <someOtherElementIdontNeed />
    <div>...</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
    body *:not(.printable) {
        display: none;
    }
    .printable {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

JS: (I have somewhere in the HTML that triggers this(to print))

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#print").click(function(event){
        jQuery("#printthis").addClass("printable");
        jQuery("#printthis *").addClass("printable");
        window.print();
    });
});
```

Basically, I want all the contents of the `<table>` be printed except everything else that is not inside the tag. I triggered a jQuery.addClass to distinguish whatever is printable from what is not.

JS script seems to be working fine, I checked through chrome dev tool, its being appended. My css just don't seem to recognize them.

Isn't this what's suppose the `:not()` selector is designed to handle? When print is triggered, all I'm getting is a blank page... displaying all elements as `none` which doesn't exempt those with `.printable` class

Comment: `jQuery("#print").click(function(event)){
        jQuery(":not(#printthis)").addClass('dontprint');
        window.print();
    });`

in css. `.dontprin{display:none}` can you try like this

Comment: All the elements INSIDE the printable classes are still getting set display: none. That is why you don't see anything.

Comment: @user3154108, care to explain further? I'm thinking they're exempt from that rule.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: check my answer below. it was a minor problem

Comment: @vittore testing this on latest google chrome browser

Comment: edited my answer below. it'a all about using classes instead of ids ( can't have duplicate ids )

Answer (score 2):

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/pfL5nk9x/4/)**

**DO NOT** use same ids (#printthis) use classes instead `.printthis` 
 you cannot have duplicate id-s only classes. that's why it doesn't work for you but it works  only in this example where there is a single `#printthis` id

**ALSO** . be careful not to have an element that you want to print..inside another element that doesn't have the class `.printthis`

for eg do not use

```
 <div>
    <div class="printthis"> PRINT ME </div>
</div>
```

after adding the `.printable` class with JQ to all the elements with `.printthis`, the code from

```
@media print {
 body *:not(.printable) { display:none }
}
```

will hide the parent element and so any child of that element won't be visible when you print

UPDATED JS CODE

```
 jQuery("#print").click(function(event){
    jQuery(".printthis").addClass("printable");
    jQuery(".printthis *").addClass("printable");
    window.print();
});
```

UPDATED html :

```
<body>
<div>DO NOT PRINT</div>
<table class="printthis">
    <tr>
        <td>SHOW</td>
        SHOW
        SHOW
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="printthis">TESTPRINT</div>
<someOtherElementIdontNeed />
<div>DO NOT PRINT</div>
<button id="print"> PRINT</button>
</body>
```

Css :

```
@media print {
body *:not(.printable) {
    display: none;
}
.printable {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the extra `)` that closes the `(document).ready` clause? EDIT: it's a typo sorry

Comment: no you had and extra `)` after the `(event)` you had this : `.click(function(event)){` you should have`.click(function(event){`

error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

i removed the `(document).ready` because it's not necessary in `jsfiddle` but you can keep it

Comment: Yes, I noticed. It's a typo. actual code is not and is working as intended.

Comment: so...what's not working then ? in my test in the link in my answer...everything is working fine

Comment: odd. we have identical code but on my part, it's not working. I'm looooooooosing my mind

Answer (score 1):

try

```
@media print {
    body *:not(.printable, .printable *) {
    display: none;
    }
    .printable {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```